# Apache 403'ing on symlinks created by root but not symlinks created by normal user

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, symlink

Like the title said, for some reason I am getting a 403 when apache tries to follow a symlink created by the root user. For example:

**This works**

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 repxadmin psacln    15 Jan 25 02:09 httpdocs -> assets/app/web
```

**But this doesn't**

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    15 Jan 25 02:09 httpdocs -> assets/app/web
```

Same exact files on the receiving end. Is this expected behavior or is there something I can change in my server configuration to let apache follow a "root" created symlink?

If it matters the site is on centos and running plesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is almost certainly the result of the `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` setting.

Your log will tell you.  Always read server logs before posting questions.

### Further reading

- [*Apache Core Features*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html)  Apache 2.0 HTTP Server Documentation.  2011.

Comment: It's much more likely that the target directory only allows owner or group access, which means root:root ownership denies others (including apache) read access. SymlinksIfOwnerMatch will not solve this - in fact, it will make it less likely to work ;)

Comment: I tried adding "Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" to the directory in the configuration however the error message I recive has not changed. Without that and with it the error in the logs is: 
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

Comment: @Steven Is there potentially another `Options` directive applying to the request?  A `Location` block or an `.htaccess` file, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the permissions of the **target**; symlink permissions are always 777.

Also check your settings for `Options FollowSymlinks` in those locations - perhaps the physical directories are simply configured differently.

Comment: I am linking to the same exact file so that could not be an issue, the only difference between links is the owner of the link.